# Bypass ac compressor with smaller belt

Tags: serpentine-belt

My ac compressor is shreding bits of metal.I think the bearings in the pulley is bad. Can i bypass it by buying a smaller belt and bypassing the ac pulley?

Comment: Also i dont know if i need to unplug the ac compressor because i will still need to use the defroster and it makes the compressor turn on

Comment: Yes you can. Just unplug the wires which energize the clutch. Should be two wires (power & ground). This shouldn't cause you any issues. In actuality, you probably wouldn't need to unplug it at all since even it it energizes, it's not going to do anything without a belt on it.

Comment: Long-term lack of circulating freon may cause some issues within the system - seals can dry out, etc.  Just beware that you may be condemning other parts of the AC system to an early death.

Comment: Knowing the Make, Model, Year and engine size would be helpful.

Comment: @mike65535 The compressor's shaft seal can perish, o-rings can perish and the dryer and system oil charge might need replacement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, and this is definitely possible on some models of car (I know for sure that that can be done on my car and it is a belt from a Renault - can't remember which model).

You need to find the length of belt necessary, so take a piece of string and wrap it around all the pulleys, make sure the adjuster or tensioner pulley is in the compressed position and you will have the minimum length of belt required.

After that all you need to do is find a matching belt - some places are **very** helpful, others less so...